# Does anyone know why the Azure Kinect DK crashes in the viewer when WFOW(wide field of view) is used as depth configuration?

Tags: azurekinect

When the WFOV(wide field of view) depth configuration is used, the Azure kinect is failing in Kinect viewer. We tried to update the firmware but it did not work. Everytime after opening the kinect viewer for couple of seconds we receive the following errors in the viewer when crashing:

```
[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    307733 type:Color

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    374388 type:Color

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    441066 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    507733 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    574411 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    641077 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    707722 type:Color

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    774400 type:Color

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    841055 type:Color

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    907733 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:    974388 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:   1041066 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:   1107733 type:Color

[ warning  ] : usb_cmd_libusb_cb(). USB timeout on streaming endpoint for depth

[ error    ] : replace_sample(). capturesync_drop, releasing capture early due to full queue TS:   1174411 type:Color

[ error    ] : cmd_status == CMD_STATUS_PASS returned failure in depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming()

[ error    ] : depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming(). ERROR: cmd_status=0x00000063

[ error    ] : cmd_status == CMD_STATUS_PASS returned failure in depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming()

[ error    ] : depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming(). ERROR: cmd_status=0x00000063
```

Does anyone know why we are having these errors in its own viewer?

Thank you

Comment: Please have a look at this similar github issue : [replace_sample(). capturesync_drop](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/1112)

Comment: The error is similar but the issue is not solved, i found out the reason behind the warning but not behind the error. thank you for your help.

Comment: @SirajHaidar is your issue solved? If so can you post the answer? Thanks ! :)